# IntelliJ import issue while importing annotation

Tags: intellij-idea, import, annotations

I would like to know why the annotation "DataAttribute" cant be imported into the "Person" class ?. What I am doing wrong ?. It's as if being in another package, unables one to use the other.

[image]

Comment: If you hover your mouse over DataAttribute, what does the error message say? As far as I can see from the screenshot, the annotation was imported properly but is used incorrectly (e.g. you didn't specify correct attributes).

Comment: Man. How are you ?. Forgot to add this to the annotation:
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DataAttribute`
Thankx